# Limit of sequence of functions $g_n(x) = n - n^2x $

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I found the following sequence in an answer of a different question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1919759/579544

> Consider the sequence of functions $g_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
>   $$
> g_n(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> n - n^2x & \text{if } 0 < x < 1/n \\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$

How do I show that it converges pointwise to the *zero*-function?

Can you please give me a hint?

If you post the complete answer then please consider to hide it!

Comment: Take $x>0$ and $n$ large, and see how $n^{-1}$ behaves compared to $x$

Comment: For every $x$ the sequence is eventually $0$.

Comment: hmm I don't know why I didn't see this. How embarrissing. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply look pointwise : for each $x > 0$, $$n > \frac 1x \implies x > \frac 1n \implies f_n(x) = 0$$. Thus for large enough $n$, $f_n(x) = 0$ so the limit is $0$. Of course, if $x =0$ then $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$ by definition so $f_n$ identically converges to $0$. But the lack of integral covergence ($\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = \frac 12$ for all $n$ so the integrals don't converge) shows that the convergence is not uniform.

---

Proof of integral of $g_n$ : consider $g_n$ restricted to $[0,\frac 1n)$ and to $[\frac 1n,1]$. On these, apply FTC. Note that $g_n$ is discontinuous at only one point, hence Riemann integrable : it is an easy exercise to show that the integral is the sum over the two parts now. But the first is always $\frac 12$, the second always $0$.

Comment: Why is $\int^1_0 f_n(x)dx = 1$ for all $n$? How do you show it as one cannot simply apply the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Pardon me, the statement holds with a small change. : all integrals evaluate to $\frac 12$. You cannot apply FTC, but you can still note that the function is Riemann integrable being discontinuous at only one point, and then if you break the domains and apply FTC, things work out.

Comment: thanks for the further explanation. It really helped while getting familiar with _Riemann_-integration.

Comment: You are welcome!